# How can I set the calendar property on my MSProject project?

Tags: c#, interop, ms-project

I have a project of MSProject and I want to change the calendar in use. The problem is that I cannot find this property.

Here I show my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application();


 app.FileOpenEx(
                Server.MapPath("") + "\\sample.mpp",
                false,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                PjPoolOpen.pjPoolReadWrite,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing);
                pj=app.ActiveProject;

//"proyecto" is an entity
//app.GlobalBaseCalendars has all calendars
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Calendar calendar in app.GlobalBaseCalendars)
                {
                    if (calendar.Name == "Noche")
                    {
                        pj.Calendar.index? GUID? ...= // All properties are read-only
                    }
                }
```

How can I set the value of `pj.Calendar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the many cases where the project property is read only and the way to set it is to use a method of the application:

```
app.ProjectSummaryInfo(
                       Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing,
                       "Noche",
                       Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing);
```